# Cannot get JSON data from Jersey GET response

Tags: java, json, http, jersey, response

I was developing a restful web client and trying to get the JSON payload from the response of a GET method. I am using Jersey. But I just cannot read the JSON data using response.getEntity() method. I tried many methods including response.bufferEntity(), but the output always kept empty. Below is my code and output, and in addition I can see the JSON data right in the response packet captured in wireshark. I would really appreciate everyone trying to help figure out why or provide solution. Thank you!

Code:

```
    public JSONObject Get(String requestPath){

    ClientResponse response = webResource.path(requestPath)
            .header("Content-Type", contTypeHeader )
            .header("Accept",acceptHeader)
            .header("Authorization", authZ )
            .get(ClientResponse.class);

    response.bufferEntity();
    if (!(response.getStatus() == 201 || response.getStatus() == 200)) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Failed : HTTP error code : " + response.getStatus());
    }

    System.out.println(response.getEntity(JSONObject.class));
    return null;

}
```

and the output is always like this: {}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't use `JSONObject` unless you have a `MessageBodyReader` for it. See more at [JAX-RS Entity Providers](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/message-body-workers.html). The provider you are currently using (probably Jackson) only supports JavaBean POJOs or collections of them. For example if you have this JSON

```
{ "property1" : "value1", "property2": "value2" }
```

Then you would need to have a POJO like

```
public class Bean {
    private String property1;
    private String property2;
    // getters and setters
}
```

Then you can do `getEntity(Bean.class)`. The reason you are getting an empty object, is that the deserialization works off the setters. It looks for properties on the JSON, that matches a setters, and uses it the set the property. The JSON object *has* no setters for your JSON properties.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. What if the JSON is a little more complicated like this: {
  "vtn": [
    {
      "description": "VTN Hao",
      "name": "Tenant_Hao",
      "hardTimeout": "0",
      "idleTimeout": "300"
    },
    {
      "description": "VTN Jue",
      "name": "Tenant_Jue",
      "hardTimeout": "0",
      "idleTimeout": "300"
    }
  ]
} and the number of entries is uncertain. how can I define the POJO?

Comment: You will need to do through some Jackson tutorials. Start [here](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/jackson/jackson_data_binding_generics.htm) and [here](http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonInFiveMinutes).

Comment: Basically with what you provided, just have  a pojo with with a `vtn` property that is of type `List<SomeObject>`. `SomeObject` should have the properties `description`, `name`, etc